# is there a way to match Two-dimensional lists

Tags: list, arraylist, pycharm, jupyter-notebook, python-3.7

I have two list that are two dimensional list with at least 100 rows. I would like to match c1 to c2 or vice versa. But the real problem is instead of typing in row by row from c1 to match c2. Is there a faster way to loop through all the rows from c1 to match all the rows from c2 ?

I tried c1[0] and c1[1] and c1[2]. This method will work but i would have to do alot of typing row by row. This will be to much typing especially if its alot of rows?

Here i have two list that are two dimensional list.

c1 = [[2, 6, 7],[2,4,6],[3,6,8]].....

c2 = [[13, 17, 18], [7, 11, 13], [5, 6, 8]].......

[list(filter(lambda x: x in c3, sublist)) for sublist in c2].

Answer (score 0):

You can just loop through c1 and c2 adding the lists inside them to your third list.

```
for list in c1:
    c3.append(list)

for list in c2:
    c3.append(list)
```

Comment: i not trying to append them. im trying to match c1 and c2

Comment: what do you mean by "match"?

Comment: Like compare , are match the same value